# Django: Logic to execute certain part of a method associated with a URL in views.py, when URL hits 10 times

Tags: python, django, api, django-views, throttling

I am new to Django.

My Project (for example) -

```
project/            # project dir (the one which django-admin.py created)
  myapp/            # my app
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py
    ...
  project/          # settings for the project
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    wsgi.py
    ...
```

My app exposes an URL (lets say),

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/
```

When ever I call the above mentioned URL, this method is invoked in myapp/views.py -

```
def index(request):
    req_data = some_method_which_does_processing()
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'req_data': req_data})
```

**What I want achieve is the following,
I don't want "some_method_which_does_processing()" this method to be executed every time when user hits this URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/".
I want to add a logic wherein this method is called when user hits the above mentioned URL 10 times.
I want to know if Django exposes something to cover this specific scenario**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user based, single user hit the view ten times, then the function is triggerd

```
def index(request):
    try:
        request.session['hit_num'] += 1 # counter
    # first time access, reqets.session['hit_num'] does not exists yet
    except KeyError:
        request.session['hit_num'] = 1
    if request.session['hit_num'] == 10:
        req_data = some_method_which_does_processing()
        del request.session['hit_num'] # remove the hit_num from user session, so next time it will count from 1 again
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'req_data': req_data})
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html',  {'req_data': 'N/A'})
```

request based, request accumulated to ten times, function is triggered

```
COUNTER = 0

def index(request):
    global COUNTER
    COUNTER += 1
    if COUNTER == 10:
        req_data = some_method_which_does_processing()
        COUNTER = 0 #  from 0 again
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'req_data': req_data})
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'req_data': 'N/A'})
```

Comment: First suggestion works perfectly fine. Thanks @minglyu!